# Get longitude and latitude by touch event

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, touch-event

How can i get the longitude and latitude of a place by touch event on marker. I want when user click on map somewhere it will get its latitude and longitude. Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just override the [`onMapClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html#onMapClick%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%29) method of [`GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html) class. You will get the `LatLng` point of the clicked area, then :

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double lat = point.latitude;
        double lng = point.longitude;    
    }
});
```